# Oracle connection compression?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, compression

I have an application that uses JDBC to connect to Oracle 11g.  Unfortunately, the machine my app is running on and the Oracle machine are connected via a somewhat low bandwidth connection.  I haven't sniffed the connection, but I am pretty sure the data streaming across the connection is not compressed.  For my application, I'm more concerned about bandwidth than latency.

Is there any way to tell the JDBC driver and Oracle to compress the data going through the connection?  Google comes up with a lot of answers for data file compression, but I couldn't find anything about network protocol compression.

I'm using Oracle's thin driver, but if this is only supported by the OCI driver, I could switch to that.  Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To directly answer the question, the drivers (thin or OCI) have no such mechanism for compression. And since the data sent is likely in some funky binary format I'm not sure that it will compress well over SSL. Some other mechanism for improving network performance will need to be employed.

Comment: Using compression with SSH tunnels with JDBC can reduce latency

Answer (score 11):

I don't know specifics about Oracle's thin and OCI drivers. But you could use [SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) tunnels to achieve [compression](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ssh+1).

1. So, in your Oracle machine, you setup a SSH daemon. If your Oracle server is running under RedHat Linux, you're done
2. On your client machine (the one that hosts your application that connects through JDBC) setup a SSH connection, enabling a compressed tunnel. You can use command line SSH or [Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) (if you are under windows) to do that.

Setup the connection to something like this:

```
$ ssh -L1521:localhost:1521 username@oracleserver_ip
```

Then, in your application, use localhost:1521 as Oracle's address.

Comment: No, a VPN connection will certainly **not** work.  There's a limited amount of bandwidth - adding VPN overhead is going to ensure that *less* actual data is stored per packet.

Comment: While that is a possibility, I'm hoping to see if the Oracle driver has this built-in, to keep it simple.

Comment: This is not a VPN. It's just a tunnel. And it **will** work. If you use a compressed tunnel and what you are trying to transmit can be compressed (like huge amounts of text or XML) it will be compressed.

Comment: @joev I know that it will be easier to just have a flag in the driver or a parameter in the URL, but this is all I know. :-) 
Maybe there's something on URL connection parameters documentation...

Comment: SSH is an encrypted tunnel (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol) making it a defacto VPN. That said, it could well work, if the compression ratio is good enough to overcome the VPN/tunnel overhead.

Comment: Without any remote account allowing ssh port-forwarding, tunneling via ssh will not be possible. So in case you have just the Oracle-Connection, it's not an option.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, high latency harms performance using the Oracle JDBC drivers far more than low bandwidth. (at least in the application I work on). You say you aren't worried about latency, but could you give an estimate on the latency of your low-bandwidth environment?

How big is the data you're sending? Are there BLOB columns? Are there other technologies involved, like a connection pool, or Hibernate? There are a lot of potential factors, not just if your data is being compressed.

Have you done any WAN emulation to try to isolate what is degrading your performance most? 
[WANem](http://wanem.sourceforge.net/) is pretty easy to setup.

I've spent weeks on this problem, and 100-200ms latency hurt us much more than a 1Mbit bandwidth limitation. Hopefully you are in a different boat - compression an easier problem to solve.

Comment: 64 bytes pings are only taking 4ms to be ack-ed, so that's not so bad.  No BLOBs, but a lot of INSERT activity.  No connection pooling, it's a single connection.  Staffing is a little light for the holidays, so I can't get into deep WAN diagnostics for the moment.  That seemed like the next obvious thing to look at.  But thanks for the pointer to WANem, I'll look into that!

Comment: If it's only 4ms, I'm going to say you're right in that latency should play a very minimal role.

Answer (score 4):

Just an Update.

Oracle JDBC connections in 12.2 now have compression feature as disclaimed in this post: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/jdbc-faq-090281.html#0000_00

Answer (score 3):

Refer to [Oracle JDBC Developer's guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdbc/data-sources-and-URLs.html#GUID-6D8EFA50-AB0F-4A2B-88A0-45B4A67C361E) for enabling the network compression. Note that this is an Oracle12c Release 2 feature.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question and answers are out of date or links broken, adding method to enable connection compression.

**Database server side:**

Check with your DBA to configure file : $DB_HOME\NETWORK\ADMIN\sqlnet.ora

Add below lines :

```
SQLNET.COMPRESSION=on
SQLNET.COMPRESSION_THRESHOLD=1024
SQLNET.COMPRESSION_LEVELS=(high)
```

The default value of `SQLNET.COMPRESSION_LEVELS` at server is `(low)`. This can work fine if using OCI driver, but if using the generally recommended *thin* driver, it needs to be specifically configured to `(high)`.

**Client side Java code:**

```
DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
OracleDataSource ds = new OracleDataSource();

Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.setProperty("user", "myuser");
prop.setProperty("password", "mypassword");
prop.setProperty("oracle.net.networkCompression", "on"); 
prop.setProperty("oracle.net.networkCompressionThreshold", "1024");

ds.setConnectionProperties(prop);
ds.setURL("jdbc:oracle:thin:@<HOSTNAME>:<PORT>/<SERVICENAME>");

Connection conn = ds.getConnection();
```

Note that, if you enable compression high, the CPU usage can increase on both client and particularly on database server. Unless the network latency is really an issue, this is a choice you need to make.

Answer (score 0):

This JDBC connect string syntax is acceptable and seems to work:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@(description=(COMPRESSION=on)(COMPRESSION_LEVELS=(LEVEL=high))(address=(host=host1)(protocol=tcp)(port=1521)) (connect_data=(SERVICE_NAME=SERV1)(SERVER = DEDICATED)))
```